# reactjs on page load ajax calls, console.log etc are called from accross components even if those components are not executed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have 2 main components, `Home` and `Login`.

`Login`: logs the user in and redirects to home component

`Home`: does API call get some data.

At `Login` component in `componentDidMount()`, i have a `console.log()`. The `console.log` gets executed on both `Login` and `Home` component even that its only present on `Login` component.

At `Home` component in `componentDidMount()`, i have `getData()` method. 
The `getData()` method gets executed on both `Login` and `Home` component even that its only present on `Home` component.

I am not sure if this is do to redux rehydrate. Is there a way to prevent actions unique to a specific component being executed at the different component?

store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import reducer from './reducer';
import homeReducer from './homeReducer';
import {autoRehydrate, persistStore} from 'redux-persist';
import localForage from 'localforage';

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    reducer,
    homeReducer
  }),
  {},
  applyMiddleware(thunk, logger),
  autoRehydrate()
);

persistStore(store, {storage: localForage})
export default store;
```

Login Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login, setLogingSuccess } from '../../actions/loginActions';
import  {Header}  from '../Shared/header';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import cookies from 'universal-cookie';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     //...
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('login component');
   //...
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   //...
  }

  render() {
    //...

    return (
      <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

        <h3>Login</h3>
        <form name="LoginForm">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={e => this.setEmail(e)}
          />
          <br />
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="password"
            name="password"

            onChange={e => this.setPassword(e)}
          />
          <br />
          //...
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
  };

 //...
}
LoginForm.propTypes = {
//...
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    //...
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    //...
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Home component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';

import Header from '../Shared/header';

import {
  //...
} from '../../actions/homeActions';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //...
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getData();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    //...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <Header />
        <div>
          <h3>Home</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getData = function(){
    axios.get('/_/data/')
      .then(success =>{
        console.log(success);
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        console.log(error)
      });
  };
}

Home.propTypes = {
 //...
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
//...
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
//..
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm/LoginForm';
import Home from './components/HomePage/home';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Route />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home} />
              <Route path={'/login'} component={LoginForm} />
              <Route path="*" component={LoginForm} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: show the part of the code that mounts `LoginForm`

Comment: @FuzzyTree login form and home are managed by router: https://jsfiddle.net/mx29aL97/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered couple issues while improving the solution to this issue:

1. When i would re-hydrate auth values, they were not properly reset
   when user logged out
2. Proper way to manage auth is through the router and not though the components. This prevents needless api calls or state changes.
3. I did some research and found the following guide: https://codepen.io/bradwestfall/project/editor/XWNWge?preview_height=50&open_file=src/app.js which i have used to adjust the auth issue

I have added a new component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import cookies from 'universal-cookie';

class AuthorizedRoute extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {}

  getAuth() {
    const cookie = new cookies();
    return cookie.get('auth');
  }

  render() {
    const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => {
          return this.getAuth() ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect to="/login" />
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

AuthorizedRoute.propTypes = {
  render: PropTypes.any,
  component: PropTypes.any
};

export default AuthorizedRoute;
```

Updated index.js route switch statement to:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm/LoginForm';
import Home from './components/HomePage/home';
import AuthorizedRoute from './.../AuthorizedRoute';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Route />
            <Switch>
              <AuthorizedRoute exact path={'/'} component={Home} />
              <Route
               exact
               path={'/login'}
               render={props => <LoginForm {...props} />}
               />
              <Route path="*" render={props => <LoginForm {...props} />} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Reinitialized auth vars in login component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const cookie = new cookies();
    const auth = cookie.get('auth');
    if (auth) {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    } else {
      if (this.props.isLoginSuccess) {
        this.props.setLogingSuccess(false);
        this.props.setLoggedUser(null);
      }
    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { isLoginSuccess } = this.props;
    if (!isLoginSuccess && nextProps.isLoginSuccess) {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    }
  }
```

Updated reducer REHYDRATE to only story needed info:

```
case REHYDRATE:
      var incoming = action.payload.reducer;
      if (incoming) {
        return {
          ...state,
          loggedUser: incoming.loggedUser,
          isLoginSuccess: incoming.isLoginSuccess,
        };
      }
      break;
```